# Perl DBI — ignore few columns in output

Tags: perl, dbi

I've used this code:

```
while (my $line = <IN>)
{
chomp $line;
if($line =~ /(.*?: )\{(.+)\}/)
{
my $value2 = $2;
my @values2 =  split(/,/, $value2);

my $insertKeys;
my $insertValues;
foreach $data(@values2)
{
chomp $data;
my ($key, $value) = split(/:/, $data);
$key =~ s/"//g;
$value =~ s/"/'/g;
$insertKeys .= $key.',';
$insertValues .= $value.',';
}
```

Input:

"actor_ip":"127.0.0.1" "note":"From Git" "user":"Username for 'https" "user_id":null "actor":"Username for 'https" "actor_id":null "org_id":null "action":"user.failed_login" "created_at":1412256345456789 "data":{"actor_location":{"location":{"lat":null "lon":null}}}

Output:

KEYS: actor_ip,note,user,user_id,actor,actor_id,org_id,action,created_at,data,lon,

VALUES: '127.0.0.1','From Git','Username for 'https',null,'Username for    'https',null,null,'user.failed_login',1412256456789,{'actor_location',null

I want to remove these two key and values from output Please let me know how to regex these below

```
"user":"Username for 'https"    

"data":{"actor_location":{"location":{"lat":null "lon":null}}}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  I'm not clear where your data is coming from.  It looks like a bastardized JSON format.  You've omitted the code that you've said you've used.  You've not given the schema of the table you're trying to insert into.  It isn't clear whether the input is a single line or multiple lines.  It isn't clear which columns you're omitting in the output, or in the insert.  In fact, in general, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to exclude the keys you don't want:

```
if ($key !~ /^(data|user)$/)
{
    $insertKeys .= $key.',';
    $insertValues .= $value.',';
}
```

However, a more flexible design might be to insert key/value pairs into a hash:

```
my %params;

foreach $data(@values2)
{
    chomp $data;
    my ($key, $value) = split(/:/, $data);
    $key =~ s/"//g;
    $value =~ s/"/'/g;
    $params{$key} = $value;
}
```

Then it would be easy to do whatever you want with the parameters later.

Also, you don't show your DBI code, but this code suggests you are manually building the whole insert query string.  A safer (and better-designed) approach would be a [parameterized query](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/dbi/ch05_03.htm).